# Using Animation to swipe views

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a FrameLayout that recognize swipe gestures (up and down).

For example: if a swipe up are performed, I should animate the current view (that is MATCH_PARENT x MATCH_PARENT) to goes up at the same time a new view come from bottom.

I can achieve this with animations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this way:

```
private void swipeUp() {
    current.currentPage++;

    final View hidingView = currentView;
    TranslateAnimation hide = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -getHeight());
    hide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            hidingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
    hide.setDuration(1000);
    hidingView.startAnimation(hide);

    TranslateAnimation show = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, getHeight(), 0);
    show.setFillAfter(true);
    show.setDuration(1000);

    View nextView = getView();
    addView(nextView, createLP());

    nextView.startAnimation(show);
    currentView = nextView;
}
```

Comment: Setting the view to GONE isn't a bad way to make the animation work, but if it's going to run multiple times, you need to make sure you actually dispose of the previous View.  Otherwise, you risk performance and memory issues since View.GONE doesn't actually dispose of the View.

Comment: Okay, i'll use removeView instead.

Comment: Do the View.GONE first, then when the animation is complete, remoteView :)

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that when just removing, this give error on dispatchDraw

Answer (score 1):

If you want to actually switch views, you need to implement an [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) that takes care of the animation.  If you want more complex behavior like a "finger following" scroller between views, you will likely have to use something a bit more complex, but if you're just saying

```
if(I flicked upwards)
    move view up
```

then AnimationListener is perfect for you.  Just make sure you set the listener to the `Animation` in code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, I used the AnimationListener to setVisibility(View.GONE), but it's not the answer I was looking for.

Comment: You want to actually setContentView()