# ViewSwitcher and ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, ontouchlistener, viewswitcher

I have following layout

```
<ViewSwitcher>
  <LinearLayout>
    <ListView />
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout>
    <ListView />
  </LinearLayout>
</ViewSwitcher>
```

But when I switch ViewSwitcher(by onTouchListener) the onItemClickListener of ListView in my layout responds too. I do not need that on switching. How to fix it?

This is my switcher class:

```
public class MMGViewSwitcher extends ViewSwitcher{
private float startX = 0;
private float startY = 0;
private float endX = 0;
private float endY = 0;


public MMGViewSwitcher(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context,attrs);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    String ActionString="";
    switch(event.getActionMasked())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startX = event.getX();
            startY = event.getY();
            ActionString="ACTION_DOWN";
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
            ActionString="ACTION_MOVE";
            break;
        case MotionEvent.EDGE_LEFT:
        this.showNext();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.EDGE_RIGHT:
        this.showPrevious();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
            endX = event.getX();
            endY = event.getY();
            if((startX > endX) && Math.abs(startX-endX)>30){
                this.showNext();
            }
            if((startX < endX) && Math.abs(startX-endX)>30){
                this.showPrevious();
            }
            ActionString="ACTION_UP";
        break;
    }
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    onTouchEvent(ev);
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First: Be more patient than an hour before you comment on your own question asking again for an answer (not welcome in the community).

Your issue is that you use two listeners that interfere each other. I don't know on which rule your `OnTouchListener` flips the view, but you should replace it with a `GestureDetector` and a `SimpleGestureListener`. There you can implement a swipe gesture detection to flip your view.

Comment: I create my own view extended viewSwitcher and override onTouch event. that work is good, but when i flip the view  - onClickListener responds together. as a result a have flip and onclick simultaneously. Its wrong for me. May I disable Onclick's of childrens from my switcher? But why?

Comment: Your gesture detector should work on the viewswitcher, not on the children. If you have problems, ask a new question here.

Comment: hello. I refresh my question, please look it. It's work good, switcher has 2 layouts with tabs. but when I moving on ListItem which have onClick listener - both listeners responds. I need to response only of OnTouch when i do not click on the listItem. Maybe you have answer why I may disable onClick at the time of   OnTouch or good example with GestureDetector for my case?

Comment: @Maxim maybe your have ansver?

Comment: I still can't see a gesture detector... the way you do that is simply wrong. Sorry but without a gesture detector you will have this issue. I will not help if you didn't react on my advises...

Comment: i am tryin gesture detector from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184382/how-to-implement-both-ontouch-and-also-onfling-in-a-same-listview . But it's don't work for me. Maybe you have example...

Comment: As I said before: if you have trouble with the GestureDetector, make a new question.

Comment: tell me please where I must implement gesture detector: in activity or switcher class?

Comment: You don't get what I am telling you, right? Make a new question for it! Can you read what is right above this input text when you type your next comment? **Please avoid extended discussions in comments.**

Comment: sorry. it's a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378010/vievsvitcher-and-gestures-probl